# PowerShell: "Access is denied" doesn't show as "Audit Failure" in Event Viewer

Tags: powershell, authentication, event-log

From my previous question I figured out a way to login into a PC.
While on the domain, on a different computer, I remote to another PC and attempt to fail login.

By doing so I get the following error [which I believe is what I want]:

[image]

However, when I login into the PC that I am trying to fail login to, there isn't anything in the Event Viewer log showing my "failed login".

```
$Username = 'domainname\username'
'correct password
#$Password = get-content "Z:\folder1\passwordhash.txt" | convertto-securestring
'fail login password
$Password = "test" 
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force

$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

gwmi win32_computerSystem –credential $MySecureCreds –computer PC#
```

Any suggestions on why Event Viewer Log doesn't read PowerShell's failed login?

Only time Event Viewer shows Audit Failure is when I actually manually try to fail a login for username and password into a remote login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The Audit Failure (EventID 4625) error is logged on the Domain Controller.

**Long Answer:**

If you try to log in with a nonsensical username (non domain username) For ex. `$username = "DoesNotExist\user"`  Then the computer that you are logged on will treat it like a local user (i.e. it doesn't match the current computer's domain, and hence doesn't know how to properly authenticate it, so pass it on). When the credentials are sent to the receiving computer, it will see that the username/password don't match anything that it knows about and will fail it, and log an Audit Failure on the machine that you were trying to connect to.

If you try to log in with a Domain username, then your machine will know about the Domain and try to authenticate the user against your Domain controller. If the password is wrong, this fails, and the **Domain controller** will log the Audit Failure message. It logs the Username that tried authenticating, as well as the Client address of your local machine that tried to attempt the connection.

It is a little more complicated if you have more than one Domain Controller, as it will go to the one that your machine is currently connected to. To get the information, execute `echo %LOGONSERVER%` on a command prompt.

Comment: Through testing I see the program is now connecting to the correction domain and grabbing the log ID that I needed. the echo command helped a lot too!